# Битовое сравнение символов Python

Tags: python, строки, битовые-операции

Необходимо на python'е вычислить битовую разницу символов.

Т.е., грубо говоря, символ "a" и символ "b" будут иметь разницу 1, символы "m" и "o" - разницу 2. и т.д.

С помощью массивов - не вариант, сравниваться могут любые символы юникода.

Что-то наподобие расстояния Левенштейна, только между символами и разница между символами будет равна разнице суммы их битов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас странная формулировка. При подсчете разницы суммы битов разница между "a" и "b" будет равна нулю:

```
"a" = 01100001
"b" = 01100010
```

В обоих случаях сумма равна 3, а 3 - 3 = 0.

Если же брать количество отличающихся битов, то их два.

Если взять двоичное представление чисел, соответствующих "a" и "b" в виде строк, то расстояние Левенштейна тоже будет 2.

В общем предполагаемая вами методика подсчета расстояния непонятна, догадаться как вы получили 1 мне не удалось.

В любом случае, если нужен подсчет числа единичных битов, то наиболее простой способ в Python таков (сразу оговорюсь, что есть куда более эффективные в вычислительном плане способы такого подсчета):

```
bin(ord('a')).count('1')
```

Если же вам нужно получить количество бит, которые различаются, то делается это так:

```
bin(ord('a') ^ ord('b')).count('1')
```

Здесь сначала вычисляется *исключающее ИЛИ* (*XOR*), у значения которого единичны будут те разряды, которые единичны либо в "a", либо в "b", но не одновременно (то есть различающиеся разряды), а затем, как выше, подсчитывается количество единичных разрядов (то есть тех самых различающихся разрядов).

Больше без правильной формулировки задачи сказать, увы, сложно. Уточните задачу, чтобы можно было сказать что-то более конкретное.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
print(ord('o') - ord('m'))
```

Comment: это работает для `ab`, `om` примеров, но не имеет отношения к "разнице суммы их битов".

Answer (score 0):

Речь о числе отличающихся бит что ли?
Тогда как-то так

```
delta=ord('b') ^ ord('a')
bitCount=0
maxBit=16
for i in range(0,maxBit):
  mask = 1 << i
  if (delta & mask)!=0 :
    bitCount += 1
```

Насчёт записи битовых операций и range могу таки ошибаться
Хотя не - судя по всему, всё же не то, что нужно...